# Set file expiry date for AWS S3 with aws-sdk in Ruby/Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I use the aws-sdk gem to upload files in my Rails app to AWS S3, which works quite fine. Now I want to set an expiry date for some files to improve performance.

According to the SDK documentation (http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdkforruby/api/Aws/S3/Object.html#upload_file-instance_method) this should work adding an :expires ... into the options hash of the upload_file method:

```
expire_date = 1.day.since.httpdate
obj = S3_BUCKET.object(path)
obj.upload_file("/tmp/file.png", {acl: 'public-read', expires: expire_date})
```

Files are getting uploaded successfully but in the Bucket the file still show "Expiry Date: None" ... I tried using "Time.now" with or without .httpdate and so on, nothing works...

Every help very much appreaciated!

Comment: You're getting two concepts confused. What are you actually wanting to do?  Have files disappear from the bucket after a certain time?

Comment: No, I want to set the file headers for typus "Expires" and/or "Cache-Control: max-age" to use browser caching and improve performance as written e.g. here https://developers.google.com/speed/docs/insights/LeverageBrowserCaching